# React to an older message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I haven't been able to find anything on this topic online. Is there a way to tell your bot to react to an older message? Something like:

1 - Toaster: Hey

2 - Jonathan: !!react

would make the bot react to Toaster saying "Hey"? or something even older, doing something like `!!react 5` reacting to a message 5 messages up. I don't have any code for this, but I know discord.js well and know how to add reactions to messages normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested and working:

```
const amount = (parseInt(msg.content.split(' ')[1])) + 1;

    msg.channel.fetchMessages({
        limit: amount,
    }).then((messages) => {
        var i = 0;
        messages.forEach(function(message) {
            i++;
            if (i == amount) {
                message.react("✅").catch(console.error);
            }
        })
    });
```

Edit: I don’t know what your command handler setup is like, so depending on that the code might need some tweaks.

Comment: You were right, it did need some editing, (my variable for messages is 'message', not 'msg') but this works! Thank you so much!